# How I can find out how many vectors are processed in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a very long dictionary containing more than 1 million keys.

```
df['file'] = files
df['features'] = df.apply(lambda row: getVector(model, row['file']), axis=1)
```

Below is getVector function:

```
vector=model.predict(inp.reshape(1, 100, 100, 1))
print(file+ " is added.")
return vector
```

But, it shows blahblah.jpg is added but it has no use as I do not know how many files have been processed.
My question is that how I get the count of files that has been processed?

For example,

> 1200 out of 1,000,000 is processed.

or even just

> 1200

I do not want to have a neat and clean output. I just want to know how many files have been processed.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: I think there's no easy way to do it with apply... the `getVector` function what return has?

Comment: @UlisesBussi, it returns "df". I think there should be a way to returns the count. But, this a vectorized calculation and there is no loop that I can use an index to increment every iteration.

Comment: I suggest that you add a new columns first  in df w inside your getVector function you increment the values in that column ( it could be even an increment of the new column value of the first row)

Comment: @David if returns `df` then it's processing all rows...

Comment: you maight modify your function to return 2 values `(theOriginalOutput, procBool)` and with this new column you can count how much were procesed

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a column in the initial dataframe with incremental numbers? You would use this column as an input of your getVector function and display the value.
Something like this:

`df['features'].apply(lambda row: getVector(model, row['file'], row['count']), axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a decorator to count it:

```py
import functools
def count(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrappercount(*args):
        func(*args)
        func.counter+=1
        print(func.counter,"of 1,000,000 is processed.")
    func.counter=0
    return wrappercount

@count
def getVector(*args):
    #write code and add arguments
```

Learn more about decorators [here](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/).

If you're having a class of which you want to count a method's usage, you can use the following:

```py
class getVector:
     counter=0
     def __init__(self):#add your arguments here
         #write code here
         getVector.counter +=1
         print(getVector.counter,"of 1,000,000 is processed.")
```